# AttributeError("'list' object has no attribute 'keys'",) in flask with sqlachemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I'm new to flask and python When i try retrieving from my database in my flask application with "LIKE %s" i get AttributeError("'list' object has no attribute 'keys'",) but if i use a placeholder "title =:result" i'll retrieve just one row but i can't use a LIKE clause i can only retrieve the exact data i have in my database don't know how to solve the issue i have at hand, any help will be highly appreciated.

Application.py

```
@app.route("/search",methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search():    
  if request.method=='GET':
       return render_template("search.html")
       #search=request.form.get['search']
    else:
        try:
            res =request.form.get('search')
            likeString = "'%%"+res+"%%'"
            if likeString!="":
                #return (res)
                results=db.execute('''SELECT title FROM books WHERE title LIKE %s;''', likeString).fetchall()
                #results=db.execute("SELECT title FROM books WHERE title =:result",
                #{"result": res}).fetchall()
                if results is None:
                   return render_template("error.html", message="No such book")
                else:

                   return render_template("search.html",results=results)
            else:
                return ("you didn't enter a search value")

        except Exception as e:
                raise ValueError ("could not retrieve from database",e)
```

I'll be extremely grateful if i can get any help. Thanks in advance!

Traceback

```
    File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2309, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2295, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1741, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2292, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1815, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1718, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 35, in reraise
raise value
File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "/home/ochula/Downloads/Harvard_webProgramming/Project1/application.py", line 76, in search
results=db.execute('''SELECT title FROM books WHERE title LIKE %s;''', likeString).fetchall()
File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 153, in do
return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1176, in execute
bind, close_with_result=True).execute(clause, params or {})
File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 948, in execute
return meth(self, multiparams, params)
File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 269, in _execute_on_connection
return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
File "/home/ochula/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1028, in _execute_clauseelement
keys = list(distilled_params[0].keys())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

Comment: Can you paste full error log? Seems the error is from different part of the code.

Comment: Thanks alot! i have just added it.

Comment: Please remove the `except Exception as e: raise ValueError(..., e)` wrapping and post the traceback of the original exception.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have just done that and updated my traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you everyone i was able to solve my problem i ran this query

```
 res =request.form.get('search')
        #likeString = "'%%"+res+"%%'"
        if res!="":
            #return(res)
            results=db.execute("SELECT * FROM books WHERE (LOWER(isbn) LIKE LOWER(:res)) OR (LOWER(title) LIKE LOWER(:res)) OR (author LIKE LOWER(:res)) LIMIT 10",
            { "res": '%' + res + '%'} ).fetchall()
```

And it did the magic for me!

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly suggest using sqlalchemy orm functionality instead of building your own sql queries. First you declare a class like

```
class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    title = Column(String, primary_key = True)
```

Then you can use

```
books = sess.query(Book).filter(Book.title.like(likeString))
```

Comment: While sound advice, please avoid answering questions without a MCVE with a tangential answer, because upvoted answers hinder automatic cleanup processes, if OP fails to improve the question.

Comment: Thanks alot! Is an academic project we were instructed  not to use orm i created my table in heroku postqre db  and a connection to my database.